# Use multiple bibliographystyle?

Tags: bibliographies

I am using `IEEEtran` as `bibliographystyle` which presents the citation as numbers. In some text I need to write the name of authors. However, `IEEEtran` can only use `\cite{..}` to give numbers. I would like to ask how can I use multiple `bibliographystyle` that don't make conflicts (i.e., give the ability to cite by numbers `\cite{..}` or author name `\citep{..}` in the text, having the same list of Biblography as numbers at the end of the document)

Comment: You have to use `Natbib` package to use `\citet{key}`. This means that there will be conflict between `IEEEtran and Natbib`

Comment: Well, if you're submitting to IEEE, you shouldn't be using `natbib` to begin with. If you are only using the IEEE style, you should load `natbib` with the `numbers` option, use the `natbib`-friendly IEEE style `IEEEtranN` (`\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}` – notice the extra uppercase 'N' at the end), and use `citet{key}`.

Comment: I tried it, but I have `(author ?)` in the text when using `citet{key}` and load `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have so far causing this output.

Comment: The solution is to use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{plannit}` and use `\cite{..}` for numbers and `\citet{..}` for author name along with number